# Ant Task for excluding "Lines" in the file Starting with say ":" or "//"

Tags: java, ant, build, release-management

I wanted to tweak my build settings to avoid below problem

Problem: Ant job initiates the build based on change in the file. Say file xyz is changed. I have logic which searches all the occurrence of  file xyz in other files and folders and recompiles all these files. It is requirement and works fine in current situation. Only problem is build starts compiling all the dependent file even if there is change in comments of file.

e.g Below line Starting with ":" is comment and if someone changes name of file 
L010-PS-SECURITY or does any change is comment. This will initiate build for the file containing change and also the file in comments and dependent files will be generated(I have macro defined to look for pattern matching).

:This routine is needed similar to L010-PS-SECURITY … (This is COMMENT)

```
DW; GLB.STATUS = (*****)

--Some Logic--

END;
```

Or

```
:Check for error

DW; GLB.STATUS = (*****)
    ME; ATTENTION (Error encountered)                 :Same as L010-PS-SECURITY(This is COMMENT)
END;
```

---

Can anyone suggest Ant task to ignore or exclude the lines starting starting with ":" or "//". This essentially means that any changes in comments should not compiles the file or dependent objects. Change anywhere else in the file should trigger the build

Comment: Don't bother.  All standard Ant tasks, such as the <javac> task, will treat a file as changed even if only comments have changed.  It's not a big penalty, and detecting exactly what content has changed would require a comparison with a previous version, presumably in version control, which would be considerably more complicated than just comparing timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any chance that in can omit certain line  before compiling? Below is example of target:

Comment: <loadfile srcfile="@{javafile}" property="StripLineComments">
            <filterchain>
            <striplinecomments>
                <comment value="#"/>
                <comment value="--"/>
                <comment value="REM "/>
                <comment value="rem "/>
                <comment value="//"/>
            </striplinecomments>
            </filterchain>
            </loadfile>

Comment: I would place that <filterchain> in a <copy> task which copies all the files to a separate tree, then I would pass the copied/filtered files to your compiler.

Comment: This idea was helpful but had to switch to an ignoring the particular pattern as developers needed comments as is. I have refine the regular expression search in my task e.g

Comment: <propertyregex input="${file.name}" regexp="-" replace="_"
     property="file.pattern" global="true"/>